# I am getting error while running query of add in mongo db , in database collection rohit1 on an keys "a_image" and "b_image"

Tags: mongodb

```
db.rohit1.find({{$add:["a_image","b_image"]}}:{gt:10})
```

> E QUERY    [thread1] SyntaxError: invalid property id @(shell):1:16

Comment: Your JSON query is malformed.

Comment: you cant use `$add` in find. what is your end goal?

Comment: what do you want to achieve?

Comment: Correct for what? We have **no** idea what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: my end goal is to add two key values(let it be x and y) and the resultant value is greater than 10 ...

Comment: This is the question--------> Find galaxies with surface brightness  an ellipticity in that band greater than 0.5. ellipticity is sqrt(1-b*b/a*a) ..."a" and "b" are keys..

Answer (score 0):

You can not use $add with find in the mongodb. Instead i will suggest you to use aggregate.

First you need to create another field which is the sum of two fields `a_image` and `b_image` using $project.And, then you need to use $match to check your condition.

try this:

```
db.rohit1.aggregate([{
    $project :{
        add : {$add : ["$a_image","$b_image"]},
        field1 : "$field1"
        ... //include all the fields you want to have in the result
    }
},{
    $match : {add : {$gt : 10}}
}]);
```

For more information on [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) and [$match](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/operator/aggregation/match/), please read linked mongodb documentation.

**EDIT:**
you can use `$pow` inside `$add` in the same projection.

Try this code:

```
db.rohit1.aggregate([{
    $project :{
        add : {$add : [{ $pow : ["$a_image",2]},{$pow : ["$b_image",2]}]},
        field1 : "$field1"
        ... //include all the fields you want to have in the result
    }
},{
    $match : {add : {$gt : 10}}
}]);
```

Comment: db.rohit1.aggregate([{
    $project :{
        pow1 : {$pow : ["$a_image",2]},
  pow2 : {$pow : ["$b_image",2]},
  add1  : {$add : ["$pow1","$pow2"]}
    }
},{
    $match : {add : {$gt : 2}}
}]);                                     i am getting add1 as null in the result but the value of pow1 and pow2 are not null ,

Comment: you cannot use `pow1` and `pow2` inside `add` in the same projection. it has not been created yet.